# CSS not loading when Deployment of Angular App on openshift Kubernates with Custom Path

Tags: css, angular, nginx, deployment, openshift

Currently deploying the angular App on the OpenShift Kubernates platform Using Ngnix , The issue was if i add a custom path on the Ingress , Blank page was coming , the below error is shown on the browser console.Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/htm.But if i change the path to just / then it's loading . Below are Docker file,ngnix config and Ingress.

````
    **DockerFile:**

    FROM node:10-alpine AS builder

    WORKDIR /src/app

    COPY package*.json ./

    RUN npm install

    COPY . .

    RUN npm run build-prod

    FROM nginx:1.13.12-alpine

    COPY --from=builder /src/app/dist /etc/nginx/html

    COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

    **Ngnix config:**

    pid /tmp/nginx.pid;
    events{
    }
    http {
        include    mime.types;
        server {
          listen 9501;
          server_name data-ui;
          client_body_temp_path /tmp/nginx 1 2;
          proxy_temp_path /tmp/nginx-proxy;
          fastcgi_temp_path /tmp/nginx-fastcgi;
          uwsgi_temp_path /tmp/nginx-uwsgi;
          scgi_temp_path /tmp/nginx-scgi;
          location / {
            root /etc/nginx/html;
            index index.html index.htm;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
           }
        }
    }

    **Ingress:**
    apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
    kind: Ingress`enter code here`
    metadata:
    name:data-ui-ingress
    spec:
    rules:
    - host: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    http:
    paths:
    - path: /data
    backend:
    serviceName: data-ui
    servicePort: 9501 ```
````